# note-taking application with c# but the buttons and the double click doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows, desktop

I am learning c# I watched the tutorials and I am trying to make a simple project I found on youtube the problem is that the buttons that I put in the app don't work when I run the application and click on them they don't do anything if anyone knows what did I do wrong please tell me

this is the video that I copied from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lcjeq4NZj4&list=PL8x6sUZ1nagewDUYAcavwKB-vN_awhCR7&index=1&t=319s

> ```
> blow is to form code
> ```

```
using System.Data;

namespace Note_Taker2
{
    public partial class NoteTaker : Form
    {
        DataTable notes = new DataTable();
        bool editing = false;
        public NoteTaker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NoteTaker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notes.Columns.Add("title");
            notes.Columns.Add("Note");

            PreviousNotes.DataSource = notes;
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (editing)
            {
                notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex]["Title"] = TitleBox.Text;
                notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex]["Note"] = NoteBox.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                notes.Rows.Add(TitleBox.Text, NoteBox.Text);
            }
            TitleBox.Text = "";
            NoteBox.Text = "";
            editing = false;
        }

        private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TitleBox.Text = notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            NoteBox.Text = notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            editing = true;
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TitleBox.Text = "";
            NoteBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Not a valid note"); }
        }
        private void PreviousNotes_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            TitleBox.Text = notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            NoteBox.Text = notes.Rows[PreviousNotes.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            editing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this the desinger form code

```
namespace Note_Taker2
{
    partial class NoteTaker
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.PreviousNotes = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.Title = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.TitleBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SaveButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.NoteBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.DeleteButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.LoadButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.AddButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.Note = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PreviousNotes)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // PreviousNotes
            // 
            this.PreviousNotes.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.PreviousNotes.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.PreviousNotes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 12);
            this.PreviousNotes.Name = "PreviousNotes";
            this.PreviousNotes.RowHeadersWidth = 51;
            this.PreviousNotes.RowTemplate.Height = 29;
            this.PreviousNotes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(363, 322);
            this.PreviousNotes.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Title
            // 
            this.Title.AutoSize = true;
            this.Title.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.Title.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(374, 12);
            this.Title.Name = "Title";
            this.Title.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 24);
            this.Title.TabIndex = 1;
            this.Title.Text = "Title";
            this.Title.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // 
            // TitleBox
            // 
            this.TitleBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.TitleBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(374, 39);
            this.TitleBox.Name = "TitleBox";
            this.TitleBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(420, 30);
            this.TitleBox.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // SaveButton
            // 
            this.SaveButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.SaveButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 13.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.SaveButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 340);
            this.SaveButton.Name = "SaveButton";
            this.SaveButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(176, 46);
            this.SaveButton.TabIndex = 3;
            this.SaveButton.Text = "Save";
            this.SaveButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // NoteBox
            // 
            this.NoteBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.NoteBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(374, 99);
            this.NoteBox.Multiline = true;
            this.NoteBox.Name = "NoteBox";
            this.NoteBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(420, 339);
            this.NoteBox.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // DeleteButton
            // 
            this.DeleteButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.DeleteButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 13.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.DeleteButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(192, 392);
            this.DeleteButton.Name = "DeleteButton";
            this.DeleteButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(176, 46);
            this.DeleteButton.TabIndex = 5;
            this.DeleteButton.Text = "Delete";
            this.DeleteButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // LoadButton
            // 
            this.LoadButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.LoadButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 13.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.LoadButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(192, 340);
            this.LoadButton.Name = "LoadButton";
            this.LoadButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(176, 46);
            this.LoadButton.TabIndex = 6;
            this.LoadButton.Text = "Load";
            this.LoadButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // AddButton
            // 
            this.AddButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.AddButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 13.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.AddButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 392);
            this.AddButton.Name = "AddButton";
            this.AddButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(176, 46);
            this.AddButton.TabIndex = 7;
            this.AddButton.Text = "New";
            this.AddButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // Note
            // 
            this.Note.AutoSize = true;
            this.Note.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.Note.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(374, 72);
            this.Note.Name = "Note";
            this.Note.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 24);
            this.Note.TabIndex = 8;
            this.Note.Text = "Note :";
            this.Note.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // 
            // NoteTaker
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Note);
            this.Controls.Add(this.AddButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.LoadButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.DeleteButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.NoteBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.SaveButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.TitleBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Title);
            this.Controls.Add(this.PreviousNotes);
            this.Name = "NoteTaker";
            this.Text = "Note-Taker";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.NoteTaker_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PreviousNotes)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private DataGridView PreviousNotes;
        private Label Title;
        private TextBox TitleBox;
        private Button SaveButton;
        private TextBox NoteBox;
        private Button DeleteButton;
        private Button LoadButton;
        private Button AddButton;
        private Label Note;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's strange. None of the buttons have an event handler wired up. See towards the bottom where you have `this.Load += new System.Event.......`? You should have something like that for the buttons that wires up the Click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Right after `InitializeComponent()` is called you can wire up your click handlers like:

```
SaveButton.Click += SaveButton_Click;
LoadButton.Click += LoadButton_Click;
...etc
```